# anova.cca gives incorrect (0) degrees of freedom. how to change the DF?

Tags: r

I am working on my master thesis and i have a problem. I want to calculate the p-values from my constrained ordination model in order to use them for my model selection. i will use the variables with significant p-values to build my final model.
however, if i calculate the p-values, R gives for some variables df=0. and then it does not give me a p-value.

my data consist of fish species and abiotic variables.
my fish and abiotic data contains 12 location and each location contains different transects (some locations have 9 transects, others have 15). 
I named my rownames after the transects and then deleted the column containing the transect number.

my abiotic data frame looks like this: location is a factor, others are numeric.

```
      location Clay Sand Silt mix Gravel Organic    + 8 other variables
  1.1        1    0    0    0  50      0      50
  1.2        1    0   50    0   0      0      50
  1.3        1    0   45   10   0      0      45
  2.1        1    0   50    0   0      0      50
  2.2        1    0  100    0   0      0       0
  2.3        1    0   50    0   0      0      50
```

my fish dataframe looks like:

```
        species 1          species 2        3              4
1.1        0                    0             0               0
1.10       0                    0             0               0
1.2       0                    0             0               0
2.1        0                    0             0               0
2.2        0                    0             0               0
```

First, i do an RDA and then i extract the p-values:

m1 <- rda(fish~.+Condition(location),abiotic)
    with(abiotic,anova(m1, by='margin', perm=500, strata=location))

R does not give a p-value for all my variables, i think that this is because df=0. how can i adjust the df in order to get p-values?

```
                             Df Variance      F Pr(>F)   
location                      0  0.00000                 
Clay                          0  0.00000    Inf          
Sand                          0  0.00000    Inf          
Silt                          0  0.00000   -Inf          
mix                           0  0.00000   -Inf          
Gravel                        0  0.00000    Inf          
Organic                       0  0.00000                 
trees                        1  0.00062 0.1978  0.716   
herbs                        1  0.00243 0.7785  0.387
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: This is too old to migrate now, but would get better response on sister-site [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)